Privacy Accessed API reason 1C8F.1 not available
I am adding the PrivacyInfo file. I want to set the Privacy Accessed API Type to a value of 1C8F.1. From drop down menu, the value for code 1C8F.1 is not available. It is not showing show up in  list.
Can I manually edit the underlying xml file and just add 1C8F.1 to the array for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons ?
1C8F.1 Privacy Accessed API Reason:

Other Privacy Accessed API Reason:

Note: This question is about software programming because for all iOS applications, we need to add Privacy manifest file. It is a mandate from apple.

What happened when you tried it?

Added two images when I tried to add two different reasons.  Value of 1C8F.1 is not populated by xcode

I understand, but so what? The same point is made here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/744454 This is not new news. Just enter the string "1C8F.1" and stop. Don't worry, be happy.

Yes, just edit the XML file in another editor and add "1C8F.1" as the reason
